# multiple row textbox without textarea

Tags: html, css

I am using a textbox for input description and can be quite long to edit.  Is there a way to make it multiple row?

If this could be done in css that would be the best!

I don't want to use textarea because when it appears on a search form and people push "enter" it goes to the next line.  If you can stop that then that would be acceptable.

Comment: share the input text which you are using.

Comment: By "textbox" you mean `<input type="text">`? If so, the answer is no. You cannot make a text input more than one line. That's what you have `<textarea>` for.

Comment: you can use textarea itselft by providing row size like <textarea name="Text1" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
so this will have only 3 rows or 50 characters each.

Comment: You don't want a TEXTAREA, because it can contain multiple rows.  But you *would* like an INPUT that could contain multiple rows?  Are you simply looking for a wrapping TEXTAREA that prevents the user from pressing ENTER?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make an input element have multiple lines of text, but you can make a text box very close to an input element with just the few differences you want.

All you need to do is prevent the default action for the enter key when the enter key is pressed inside of the textarea.

```js
//When key is pressed inside elements with no-enter class
$(".no-enter").keypress(function(e) {
  //If the key pressed is the 'enter' key, prevent the default action (next line).
  if(e.keyCode === 13) e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="no-enter" placeholder="A whole lot of useless text that goes to the next line."></textarea>
```

If you would like to remove the text area's resizing property to make it look more like an input element use this in your CSS.

```
.no-enter {
    resize: none;
}
```

```js
//When key is pressed inside elements with no-enter class
$(".no-enter").keypress(function(e) {
  //If the key pressed is the 'enter' key, prevent the default action (next line).
  if(e.keyCode === 13) e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.no-enter {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="no-enter" placeholder="A whole lot of useless text that goes to the next line."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use textarea itself. use the rows with that

```
<textarea name="Text1" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
```

This way you will have only 3 rows. or you can make it to '1'.

To disable the enter key:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);" >
</asp:TextBox>
```

if you want to use it in code behind :

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return (event.keyCode!=13);");
```

Comment: This sets the number of visible rows, but it doesn't prevent the user from adding new rows by pressing ENTER.